# Regex Youtube - Set autoplay to 0 except for specific video hash

Tags: php, regex, youtube

I want to remove all references to `autoplay` in an URL - even multiple times if they exist - for all videos except the one (`Uj1ykZWtPYI`). The other settings URL parameters should remain.

```
Source: 
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/1337?wmode=transparent&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

Desired:
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/1337?wmode=transparent&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

It appends `autoplay=0` programmatically.

---

For the specified video (`Uj1ykZWtPYI`), it should behave like this:

```
Source: 
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Uj1ykZWtPYI?wmode=transparent&autoplay=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

Desired:
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Uj1ykZWtPYI?wmode=transparent&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>`
```

It appends `autoplay=1` programmatically.

---

What I've tried so far in PHP:

```
// Non-matching specific video
$content['message'] = preg_replace('/youtube.com\/embed\/([^Uj1ykZWtPYI]*)([^"&]*)/', 'youtube.com/embed/$1$2&autoplay=0', $content['message']);

// Result
// <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/W6hr-o6JiWs?wmode=transparent&autoplay=1&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">

// Matching specific video
$content['message'] = preg_replace('/youtube.com\/embed\/([Uj1ykZWtPYI]*)([^"&]*)/', 'youtube.com/embed/$1$2&autoplay=1', $content['message']);

// Result
// <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Uj1ykZWtPYI?wmode=transparent&autoplay=1&autoplay=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `str_replace('autoplay=1', 'autoplay=0'`? Then update the one you want to autoplay?

Comment: `([^Uj1ykZWtPYI]*)` means anything that doesn't have any of those letters, not that exact string.

Comment: @Chris85: I suppose but the resulting string could be messy, was hoping to sanitize it by removing all references then adding just one autoplay reference. If I can't get a regex solution I'll fall back to this. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: Noted.

Comment: You're going to need to pull the query string, iterate over it and remove the autoplays, append the `0` autoplay, and then check if the `id` is the one you want and if so update to the `1`...(or you could start off by checking if it is/isnt the id you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Matching all links without `Uj1ykZWtPYI`

You can search for this regular expression to find all matches without `Uj1ykZWtPYI` in the URL:

```
\b(src="(?:(?!Uj1ykZWtPYI|").)+?)(?:&autoplay=(?:1|0))([^"]*?)"|\b(src="(?:(?!Uj1ykZWtPYI|"|&autoplay=(?:1|0)).)+?)"
```

Then, replace the it with this (autoplay is zero):

```
$1$2$3&autoplay=0"
```

---

**Explanation:**

- `\b(src="(?:(?!Uj1ykZWtPYI|").)+?)(?:&autoplay=(?:1|0))([^"]*?)"`: The first part of the pattern looks for any characters after `src="`, which are not equal an apostrophe `[^"]` or `!Uj1ykZWtPYI` and stops at autoplay. This forms the first group. The pattern has to have the characters `&autoplay=1` or `&autoplay=0` in it. After autoplay, everything except the `"` character is included into the second group - until `"`.
- `\b(src="(?:(?!Uj1ykZWtPYI|"|&autoplay=(?:1|0)).)+?)"`: The second part matches any url without an `autoplay`, a `"` and `Uj1ykZWtPYI` in it, but otherwise is the same as the first pattern.
- If pattern 1 matches, the groups `$1` and `$2` form the valid URL without `autosave`. If it does not match, but the second one does, `$3` will contain the full URL. So, `$1$2$3` depicts in any of the two cases the full URL. `&autoplay=0` is then added to the full URL afterwards.

*This pattern only works, if autoplay is not the first argument (`?autoplay`).*

---

### Matching all links including the video code `Uj1ykZWtPYI`

If you want to match every link with `Uj1ykZWtPYI` in it to add `autoplay=1` you can use a pretty similar pattern:

```
\b(src="[^"]*?Uj1ykZWtPYI[^"]*?)(?:&autoplay=(?:1|0))([^"]*?)"|\b(src="[^"]*?Uj1ykZWtPYI(?:(?!&autoplay=(?:1|0))[^"])+?)"
```

Then replace it with this (autoplay is one):

```
$1$2$3&autoplay=1"
```

---

### Live Example

Here you can see both patterns in action (JavaScript) to replace your example string (all four example string combinations are added):

```js
// 1337 as code, including autoplay
var string1 = '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/1337?wmode=transparent&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';
// Uj1ykZWtPYI as code, including autoplay
var string2 = '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Uj1ykZWtPYI?wmode=transparent&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';
// 1337 as code, autoplay not included
var string3 = '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/1337?wmode=transparent&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';
// Uj1ykZWtPYIas code, autoplay not included
var string4 = '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Uj1ykZWtPYI?wmode=transparent&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';

var regex1 = /\b(src="(?:(?!Uj1ykZWtPYI|").)+?)(?:&autoplay=(?:1|0))([^"]*?)"|\b(src="(?:(?!Uj1ykZWtPYI|"|&autoplay=(?:1|0)).)+?)"/g;
var regex2 = /\b(src="[^"]*?Uj1ykZWtPYI[^"]*?)(?:&autoplay=(?:1|0))([^"]*?)"|\b(src="[^"]*?Uj1ykZWtPYI(?:(?!&autoplay=(?:1|0))[^"])+?)"/g;
var replacement1 = '$1$2$3&autoplay=0"';
var replacement2 = '$1$2$3&autoplay=1"';

console.log(string1.replace(regex1, replacement1));
console.log(string2.replace(regex2, replacement2));
console.log(string3.replace(regex1, replacement1));
console.log(string4.replace(regex2, replacement2));
```

Comment: Nice! I will try this out. Appreciate the efforts.